# Xcode 6 why CLLocationManager didn't return latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

Why I can get the direction but I can't get the latitude and longitude?
Do I need to get user's location information admission and write in my code?

Here's my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", manager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"%f",manager.location.coordinate.longitude);
    self.Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", manager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    self.Mag_heading.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newHeading.magneticHeading];
    self.True_heading.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newHeading.trueHeading];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: @DipenChudasama  how to accept

Comment: Just press on 'right' Tick-mark sign..which is showing under the answer with grey color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once configured, the location manager must be "started"
for iOS 8, specific user level permission is required,
"when-in-use" authorization grants access to the user's location
important: be sure to include NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription along with its
explanation string in your Info.plist or **startUpdatingLocation will not work.**

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) 
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace below code.

Use `newLocation` instead of `manager`

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    self.Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```